# Stochastic integral in Tanaka formula

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Tanaka's formula is the following result $$|B_t| = \int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s)\, dB_s + L_t$$

I can see how to show that the stochastic integral $$M_t = \int_0^t \text{sgn}(B_s)\, dB_s$$ is a martingale (by the Levy characterization).

It seems to me intuitively, though, that this integral can never take a negative value. Considering (admittedly finite variation and differentiable) linear sample paths, the result of this integral is (I think) $|B_t|$. Considering piece-wise linear sample paths is similar, though the value of the integral can at least decrease as $t$ increases, but seemingly never below 0.

So my question is, what is a possible sample path of $B$ where the stochastic integral $M$ takes a negative value at some time?

Comment: When I approximate the integral with piecewise linear sample paths, I end up with sums of the form $$\sum_j \text{sgn}(B_{s_j}) \cdot (B_{s_{j+1}}-B_{s_j}).$$ Why should this sum be non-negative?

Comment: I'm beginning to see. If the time points $s_1,\dots,s_n$ are all negative or positive, then I can't see how this sum would decrease below zero. So I think this sum can only become negative when $$s_k < 0 < s_{k+1} \text{  or  } s_k > 0 > s_{k+1}$$ Is that correct?

It is still difficult to imagine a sample path which generates a large, negative value. One which has many crossings of zero in some time interval, perhaps?

Comment: Why should it matter whether the time points are negative or positive? I don't see the point. (But, in fact, the sample path of a Brownian motion crosses $0$ infinitely often in any time interval $[0,\varepsilon]$ for $\varepsilon>0$.)

Comment: I meant $B_{s_j}$ wherever I wrote a time point, my mistake.

If the path does not cross zero before time $s_n$, then the sum will telescope up to that point, leaving us with a positive result.

Comment: I see. However, note that a Brownian motion is far from being monotone and that therefore the sum does not telescope up. Sample paths of a Brownian motion are nowhere monotone (in fact, the local mimima/maxima are dense) and this means that they wiggle around a lot. As already mentioned in my last comment, we can find for (almost) each $\omega$ a sequence $s_n \downarrow 0$ such that $B_{s_n}(\omega)=0$.

Comment: My thinking is that for the set of sample paths with $2^n - 1$ piece-wise linear components, with nodes at $\frac{k}{2^n}$, IF the sample path doesn't cross zero, then the sum above telescopes to become positive. It seems that "around half" of these sample paths must generate a negative result for the sum/integral given, as the integral is supposed to be a Brownian motion. Is this thinking true? If not, where do the larger, negative values in the sample paths of $M$ appear when we move to infinite-variation paths?

Comment: With regards to your main question: it seems to me you are asking for the behaviour of $B(\omega)$ when $\omega$ is chosen so that $M_t(\omega) < 0$ for some $t$. If so, my answer is that as far as I know you can't deduce anything about $B(\omega)$ from the behaviour of $M(\omega)$.

The reason is that $M$ is a functional of the entire Brownian motion $B$. More importantly, $M(\omega)$ is not defined as a function of $B(\omega)$. This is because the stochastic integral cannot be defined pathwise, i.e. the expression $\int_0^t \rm{sgn}(B_s(\omega)) dB_s(\omega)$ is undefined.